# Proving $\int_0^\infty x^ne^{-tx}\frac{\sin x}xdx=\frac{\sin n\theta}{(1+t^2)^{n/2}}(n-1)!$, where $\theta=\arcsin\frac1{\sqrt{1+t^2}}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, trigonometry, improper-integrals, self-learning

I have stumbled upon the PDF by Leo Goldmakher from University of Toronto, Canada, named [*Differentiation Under The Integral Sign* (PDF link)](https://web.williams.edu/Mathematics/lg5/Feynman.pdf). In that pdf, he gave a theorem (his Theorem 1, at the end of the note) which states as below:

> For any real number $t\geq0$ and any integer $n\geq 1$ we have
>
> $$\int_0^\infty x^n e^{-tx}\frac{\sin{x}}{x} dx = \frac{\sin{n\theta}}{(1+t^2)^{\frac{n}{2}}} (n-1)!$$
>
> where $\theta =\arcsin {\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+t^2}}}$

Now I didn't understand how to prove this theorem?

I know

$$\displaystyle\int_0^\infty x^n e^{-tx}\sin{x} \frac{dx}{x} =\frac{(n-1)!}{(1+t^2)^n}\left(\frac{i}{2}\left[(t-i)^n-(t+i)^n\right]\right)$$

The Author  says substituting the above into (1) and tidying up a bit leads to this theorem.

I didn't understand how did he arrive at this theorem?

Comment: Section 3 of that PDF walks-through the author's proof in just a couple of steps. (Since it's short, it might be helpful to others here if you copied the steps into your question. The link could break in the future.) Can you say what part(s) of that argument escape you?

Comment: @Blue, please read the edited thread to know which part is difficult to understand.

Comment: If you're going to refer to "$(1)$", then you should probably state what "$(1)$" *is*. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Overall we want to prove that

$$\frac{\sin(n\theta)}{(1+t^2)^{\frac{n}{2}}} (n-1)!=\frac{(n-1)!}{(1+t^2)^n}\left(\frac{i}{2}\left[(t-i)^n-(t+i)^n\right]\right)$$

which boils down to showing that

$$\sin(n\theta)=\frac1{(1+t^2)^{\frac n2}}\left(\frac{i}{2}\left[(t-i)^n-(t+i)^n\right]\right)$$

Hence the variable $\theta$ is defined in terms of an $\arcsin$ function we may recall the logarithmic definition of the inverse sine function aswell as the exponential definition of the sine function given by

> \begin{align*}
> \arcsin(z)&=-i\log(iz+\sqrt{1-z^2})\tag1\\
> \sin(z)&=\frac1{2i}(e^{iz}-e^{-iz})\tag2
> \end{align*}

We are interested in $\sin(n\theta)$ where $\theta=\arcsin\left(\frac1{\sqrt{1+t^2}}\right)$ therefore we can deduce that

$$\theta=\arcsin\left(\frac1{\sqrt{1+t^2}}\right)=-i\log\left(\frac i{\sqrt{1+t^2}}+\sqrt{1-\frac1{1+t^2}}\right)=-i\log\left(\frac1{\sqrt{1+t^2}}[i+t]\right)$$

This leads us to

$$\sin(n\theta)=\frac1{2i}(e^{in\theta}-e^{-in\theta})=\frac1{2i}\left[\frac{(t+i)^n}{(1+t^2)^{\frac n2}}-\frac{(1+t^2)^{\frac n2}}{(t+i)^n}\right]=\frac1{2i}\left[\frac{(t+i)^n}{(1+t^2)^{\frac n2}}-\frac{(t-i)^n}{(1+t^2)^{\frac n2}}\right]$$

> $$\therefore~\sin(n\theta)~=~\frac1{(1+t^2)^{\frac n2}}\left(\frac i2[(t-i)^n-(t+i)^n]\right)$$

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
$\ds{\bbox[5px,#ffd]{\int_{0}^{\infty} x^{n}\expo{-tx}{\sin\pars{x} \over x}
\,\dd x
=
{\sin\pars{n\theta} \over \pars{1 + t^{2}}^{n/2}}\,\pars{n - 1}!}}$ where
$\ds{\bbox[5px,#ffd]{\theta \equiv \arcsin\pars{1 \over \root{1 + t^{2}}}}}$

---

\begin{align}
&\bbox[5px,#ffd]{\int_{0}^{\infty} x^{n}\expo{-tx}{\sin\pars{x} \over x}
\,\dd x} =
\Im\int_{0}^{\infty} x^{n - 1}\expo{-tx}\pars{\expo{\ic x} - 1}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] = &\
\Im\int_{0}^{\infty} x^{n - 1}\,
\bracks{\expo{\pars{-t + \ic}x} - \expo{-tx}}\,\dd x
=
\Im\int_{0}^{\infty} x^{n - 1}\,
\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}{\bracks{\pars{-t + \ic}x}^{k} -
\pars{-tx}^{k}\over k!}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] = &\
\Im\int_{0}^{\infty} x^{n - 1}\,
\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}\bracks{\pars{t - \ic}^{k} -
t^{k}}\,{\pars{-x}^{k} \over k!}\dd x
\\[5mm] = &\
\Im\braces{\Gamma\pars{n}\bracks{\pars{t - \ic}^{-n} - t^{-n}}} =
\pars{n - 1}!\,\Im\bracks{\pars{t - \ic}^{-n}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\pars{n - 1}!\,\Im\braces{\bracks{\root{t^{2} + 1}
\exp\pars{\ic\,\arctan\pars{-\,{1 \over t}}}}^{-n}}
\\[5mm] = &\
{n! \over \pars{1 + t^{2}}^{n/2}}
\sin\pars{n\arctan\pars{1 \over t}}
\end{align}
Note that $\ds{\arctan\pars{1 \over t} = \theta}$

Then,
\begin{align}
&\bbox[5px,#ffd]{\int_{0}^{\infty} x^{n}\expo{-tx}{\sin\pars{x} \over x}
\,\dd x} =
{\sin\pars{\theta} \over \pars{1 + t^{2}}^{n/2}}\,
\pars{n - 1}!
\end{align}